# Hibernate cannot find my Entity classes which are in a separate jar file

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My persistence.xml is located in A.jar and entity classes are in B.jar. When trying to create a query using entity manager (from A.jar), I got exception saying it cannot find NamedQueries. However, named queries are listed on the entity class using annotation.

Tried to use `<jar-file/>` to include B.jar in persistence.xml, but it doesn't work. Here's what I've tried.

```
<persistence>
   <persistence-unit name="myapp">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         ... ...
      </properties>
      <jar-file>lib/B.jar</jar-file>
      <jar-file>../lib/B.jar</jar-file>
      <jar-file>WEB-INF/lib/B.jar</jar-file>
      <jar-file>B.jar</jar-file>

      <class>com.mypackage.Bar</class>
      <class>com.mypackage.Foo</class>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Please show what you tried **exactly**.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem.

`<jar-file/>` is not necessary.

All the entity classes in jars other than current jar should be listed in `<class/>`, persistence.xml should be configured so the `<class/>` node is placed in front of `<properties/>` (XML schema defines all those nodes as **sequence**).